# Azure functions runtime configuration

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I am trying to dockerize azure functions by using the official `microsoft/azure-functions-node8` image. I could not find any documentation at all regarding configuring the runtime, and whenever I run the runtime the following errors occur:

```
      The listener for function 'Functions.health' was unable to start.
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListenerException: The listener for function 'Functions.health' was unable to start. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK 'Storage' connection string is missing or empty. The Microsoft Azure Storage account connection string can be set in the following ways:
1. Set the connection string named 'AzureWebJobsStorage' in the connectionStrings section of the .config file in the following format <add name="AzureWebJobsStorage" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http|https;AccountName=NAME;AccountKey=KEY" />, or
2. Set the environment variable named 'AzureWebJobsStorage', or
3. Set corresponding property of JobHostConfiguration.)
```

I google some bits and pieces around and managed to compose the following `.config` file, but the runtime still shouts at me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
        <add name="AzureWebJobsStorage" connectionString="myconnectionstring"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Is `.config` file format documented anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was an old tip used to remind us default storage connection `AzureWebJobsStorage` is not set correctly, which had been improved to be more intelligible long time ago. See this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/89) and [its fix](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/38).

Looks like in docker image, this fix is omitted somehow.

To solve your problem, just set `AzureWebJobsStorage` in your Dockerfile.

```
ENV AzureWebJobsStorage=DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxx;AccountKey=xxx==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net
```

Note that if you use name other than `AzureWebJobsStorage`, it's required to set the `connection` parameter using the name, in `function.json` file.

**Update**

Based on Connor's comment, the fix I mentioned is added to cli tools, which docker image doesn't utilize, so we still see this original runtime error.

Comment: The reason why the fix was omitted in the docker image is because the new error message was added to the CLI tools, so the issue would be caught before the runtime tried executing. The docker image doesn't utilize the CLI tools, so you see the original error that the runtime throws.

Comment: @ConnorMcMahon Thanks for your explanation. I will open an issue for improvement.