# Azure Function & TimerTrigger in a Custom Container: what else do I need in the function.json file?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have a custom container with a time-triggered Azure Function. When I build the Docker image, and run it locally, I don't get any action, i.e. the trigger doesn't fire.

I'm wondering - is my `function.json` missing something? Do I need an output within that, and/or in `__init__.py`? I'm starting to think that the timer trigger alone isn't enough to elicit any kind of response.

The `function.json` file:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mytimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 * * * * *",
      "authLevel": "anonymous"
    }
  ]
}
```

The `__init__.py` imports some custom functions, which work, but need the custom container for selenium concerns. The function scrapes and then outputs to Twitter. But is there a need for an output, like the [answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65232272/create-azure-timertrigger-durable-function-in-python)? If this Function needs to output to Twitter (the internet), is the timer trigger enough?

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
#importing custom modules, here, they work

def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
    
    # Class instantiation for the scraping, etc. ----
    #calling other functions
```

Some of the logs from the running container, though I don't think it's a string connection issue, as I have that defined in the `local.settings.json` file, or I use the storage emulator in VS Code, and that works too.

```
      The listener for function 'Functions.BadFunc' was unable to start.
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListenerException: The listener for function 'Functions.BadFunc' was unable to start.
 ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.Parse(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.StorageScheduleMonitor.get_TimerStatusDirectory() in C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions\src\WebJobs.Extensions\Extensions\Timers\Scheduling\StorageScheduleMonitor.cs:line 77
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.StorageScheduleMonitor.GetStatusBlobReference(String timerName) in C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions\src\WebJobs.Extensions\Extensions\Timers\Scheduling\StorageScheduleMonitor.cs:line 144
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.StorageScheduleMonitor.GetStatusAsync(String timerName)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.Listeners.TimerListener.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions\src\WebJobs.Extensions\Extensions\Timers\Listener\TimerListener.cs:line 99
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.SingletonListener.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Singleton\SingletonListener.cs:line 72
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListener.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean allowRetry) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Listeners\FunctionListener.cs:line 69
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
info: Host.Startup[413]
      Host started (154ms)
info: Host.Startup[0]
      Job host started
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /
Now listening on: http://[::]:80
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.Rpc.RpcFunctionInvocationDispatcher[0]
      Worker process started and initialized.
info: Host.Startup[0]
      Retrying to start listener for function 'Functions.BadFunc' (Attempt 1)
info: Host.Startup[0]
      Listener successfully started for function 'Functions.BadFunc' after 1 retries.
info: Host.General[316]
      Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F28FAECC'.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your function is no problem. So maybe problems come from the azure storage emulator?

Try to change the 'local.settings.json' file just like this:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=0730bowmanwindow;AccountKey=xxxxxx==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python"
  }
}
```

The value of AzureWebJobsStorage needs you to create a storage on azure and then get the connection string of it:

[image]

You can do a try.

Comment: I got no change when I tried this. Not sure if its a connection string issue

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51185634)?

Add an `ENV` statement (where you define your connection string) to your Dockerfile:

```
ENV AzureWebJobsStorage=DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxx;AccountKey=xxx==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net
```